# React Module.css property syntax

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and working on improving my skills. My question is the following:
What is the difference bettwen

```
<button className={classes["button--alt"]}>Close</button>
```

and

```
<button className={classes.button}>Order</button>
```

for accessing the properties from the css file.

```
.actions button {
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #8a2b06;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.actions button:hover,
.actions button:active {
  background-color: #5a1a01;
  border-color: #5a1a01;
  color: white;
}

.actions .button--alt {
  color: #8a2b06;
}

.actions .button {
  background-color: #8a2b06;
  color: white;
}
```

I am stuck and don't seem to figure this out if anybody can give me a hint or a page or something I would highly appreciate thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the  dash `-` doesn't allows the class object to access the property directly using the dot operator such as using `classes.button--alt` so we access it using the alternate object key syntax which is using `classes["class-key"]`

Comment: what is the point then naming it "button--alt"

Comment: @andratrr this is done for readability and in large project you will probably have different types of button which will be easier to identify based on descriptive names